# Preserve the original input string as a token/term in CustomAnalyzer

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I'm using apache lucene 6.3.0 and I'm trying to implement a custom analyzer for my index which allows searching on filenames. The problem is I want to allow the user to search using the exact filename also, but the Analyzer only has individual tokens and not the original filename as one of the token.

```
Analyzer analyzer = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
           .withTokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
           .addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
           .addTokenFilter(WordDelimiterFilterFactory.class)
           .build();
```

Input:- power_shot_black_neo.txt

Expected Output:-
power_shot_black_neo.txt
power
shot
black
neo
txt

Actual output:-
power
shot
black
neo
txt

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 'character filter' juster before the 'tokenizer' to get the complete string as it is because tokenizer only consider tokens and Character filters --> Character filters are used to “tidy up” a string before it is tokenized.

For more details please refer these url:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html

Comment: I used the HTMLCharFilter but it doesn't help much, I am not able to preserve the original input string in the analyzer

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a StandardTokenizer, it'll tokenize the string as instructed. You could use a KeywordTokenizer and a WordDelimiterFilter instead, as the WordDelimiterFilter should be able to keep the original token as well.

```
new WordDelimiterFilter(tokenizer, 
    GENERATE_WORD_PARTS |
    GENERATE_NUMBER_PARTS |
    SPLIT_ON_CASE_CHANGE |
    SPLIT_ON_NUMERICS |
    STEM_ENGLISH_POSSESSIVE |
    PRESERVE_ORIGINAL, /* this preserves the original token as well */
    ...
);
```

Another option is to have a different field for the exact value, so that you can also score / weigh the fields differently.

Comment: Thanks Mats,  But what if I add an EdgeNGramFilter after these filters? it will make tokens for the preserved original filename also, which will duplicate with the others

Comment: Yup. You can add a `RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter` to remove duplicate tokens in identical positions. Otherwise you're going to have to go with multiple fields with different tokenization / processing rules.